# Referring to id that had class associated with it (phpmailer)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get a value from my html file for my phpmailer email but keep getting an unidentified index error.

the html for it is:

```
<label for="signature"></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Signature:" name="signature" id ="signature" class="amatic">


<button type="button"  id = "info" onclick="changeFont()">Confirm Signature</button>
```

The js associated with it is:

```
<script>
function changeFont() {
  var fon = document.getElementById("signature");
  if (fon.className == "amatic") {
    fon.className = 'roman';
  } else {
    fon.className = 'amatic';
  }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#info').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            signature.disabled = true;

        });

    });
</script>
```

So basically, when the user confirms their signature the font will change to a signature style and they can no longer edit that field.

When I try to call the value in Php for the email body by doing:

```
Signature: {$_POST['signature']}
```

I get the unidentified index error. Now it works when I get rid of the class, so my question how do I get the value for my email with the class associated with it?

I tried `{$_POST['signature.roman']}` but get an error with that as well. I've tried researching it but can't seem to find anything

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance

Edit: The html is part of a form as so:

When they finish the form and hit submit at the bottom of that page application.php runs.

The rest of the email sends which is why I'm confused as to why I get the error with the signature id, unless I'm missing something completely obvious?

Edit: php code now deleted

Comment: You'll have to provide more of your code. Without seeing the form-submission HTML/JS there's no way to see what/how you're sending data to PHP.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it, sorry for that

Comment: Assuming your `<input>` is part a `<form>` submission, then `$_POST['signature']` is correct. Are you wrapping it in PHP tags? Like `<php echo $_POST['signature']; ?>`? Keep in mind that you'll need an actual *submission*; a JavaScript `onclick` can't trigger a PHP `$_POST` by itself (unless you use AJAX).

Comment: where is your <form></form>? you dont even send this to your php file

Comment: I do, just didn't post the whole of the file since it's around 700 lines

Comment: I've now edited my question, as I said the rest of the email sends, just get an error with signature but it will work if I get rid of the class associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in your mind, Fields that's have `disabled` attribute are not submitted and their values are not posted.

to solve your problem use `readonly` attribute instead :

```
$(function(){
    $('#info').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        //signature element
        $("#signature").attr({readonly : true});

    });

});
```

Comment: @l15 you can edit your question by delete `php` code because your problem not related with backend side, only for `jquery/javascript` problem use.

Comment: okay I'll delete it, just had it posted because wasn't sure where the issue had been coming from

Comment: sorry one more thing I get the value now but get signature.attr is not a function as an error in my console log?

Comment: @l15 check if `signature` element is not null and refer to correct element

Comment: Yeah checked that, the error disappears if I change it to $('signature').attr({readonly : true}); but it is still editable

Comment: @l15 type `$("#signature")` 
`$.attr()` is jquery standard method to change or add attributes to selectors

Comment: Managed to get it working, changed the line to  document.getElementById('signature').readOnly = true; and now it works perfectly, thanks for your help

Comment: @l15 this method not work/supported with all browsers, use this instead : `document.getElementById('signature').setAttribute("readonly", true)`

Comment: Okay will do, thank you for your help, really appreciate it